# Generic event handlers vs inheriting event classes

Tags: c#, events, generics

This is For a C# Based Program. Can Someone Explain to me The Difference between Generic event handlers vs inheriting event classes. And if there are any - The Pros and Cons to using each of the above.

I have looked up the Definitions of each and their usages but still cant find a reasonable answer or a distinguishable reason to use one over he other.

EDIT :

I do not know if this may be of Use. but i have found a somewhat foggy possible answer from MSDN: Can Someone confirm on This??

"The advantage of using EventHandler is that you do not need to code your own custom delegate if your event generates event data. Additionally, the .NET Framework needs only one implementation to support EventHandler regardless of the event data type you substitute for the generic type parameter."

Comment: Mostly it's just a matter of how lazy use are. With generics life is easier and code shorter.

Comment: Hard to interpret, event handlers are very rarely generic and a method doesn't equal a class.  Having generic delegate types available is hard to pass up.

Comment: What do you mean by "inheriting event classes"?